# How to start gnu-screen as a daemon without losing the layout?

Tags: layout, gnu-screen

In my embedded system I have gnu/screen. 
I set a script up launching screen as soon as I SSH my board.
I am able to detach and to reattach to the session with 
screen -r
without losing my layout.

This is part of my .screenrc file

```
    ...    
    # default windows
    layout autosave on
    layout new PEMC
    split -v
    screen -t "Linux" 1 sh
    stuff "uname -a;^M $MESSAGE_FROM_GALAXY ^c"
    focus
    screen -t "Bare Metal"  2 sh  
    stuff "start_softuart.sh^M"
    focus
    select 1
    split
    focus down
    screen -t "modbus-server" 3 sh
    stuff "start_modbus_server.sh^M"
    focus up
    bind c screen 1 # window numbering starts at 1 not 0
    bind 0 select 10 
    ...
```

Everything works fine.

Now I realised it would be nice to launch the scripts even without SSH into the board.
My question is: 
how can I launch the scripts during the boot process, 
and after eventually see their outputs with my original gnu/screen layout when I SSH?

I tried to start gnu/screen in detach mode from the rc.S folder with the following

```
su - root -c "screen -dm -S screenstartup /home/root/.screenrc"
```

It starts screen in detach mode and I have my modbus_server running properly.
However, as soon as I SSH I lose my gnu/screen layout.

How can I prevent this?
Shall I start gnu-screen from the run level 5?

Thanks in advance

Comment: GNU screen is not the appropriate technology here. You should use systemd or an init script to start and manage your modbus_server program.

Comment: Don Cruickshank, thanks a lot for your answer.
I will start my modbus_server with an init script and I will try to attach my screen window to it whenever I SSH the board.
Thanks